# Получить значение ячейки

Tags: c#

Как добавить в `MyTimers.Last().Parameter` значение ячеек

```
public class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
    public object Parameter { get; set; }
}

class WriteToFile
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection()){
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********";

        cn.Open();

        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select s.id, s.name_ru, s.sendType, c1.cod, s.typPeriod, c2.name_ru, s.metaAlg, m.cod, s.dt_send, s.dt_beg, s.dt_send_daytime, s.dt_period_end from FROM Shedule s  inner join ClBaseItem c1 on s.sendType=c1.id inner join ClBaseItem c2 on s.typPeriod=c2.idinner join MetaAlg m on s.metaAlg=m.id", cn))

        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
                myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row["dt_send_daytime"]);
                myTimer.Parameter = row["cod"];
                myTimer.Parameter = row["dt_beg"];
                myTimer.Parameter = row["dt_period_end"];  

                myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
                myTimer.AutoReset = true;
                myTimer.Enabled = true;                  
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Значение ячеек чего (dataGridView,...)?

Comment: Значение ячеек DataTable

Comment: @SeM ошибку выдает  на  MyTimers.Last().Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row["timer_int"]);    входная строка имела неверный формат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите добавить объект в конец `List<MyTimer>()`то:

```
MyTimers.Add(new MyTimer() { Interval = 1000, Parameter = dt.Rows[1]["timer_param"] });
```

### UPDATE:

Создайте новый класс с нужными вами свойствами:

```
public class ParameterData
{
    public string Cod { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt_Begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt_Period_End { get; set; }
}
```

Потом создайте объект вашего класса и присвойте нужные параметры:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{  
    . . . .
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        ParameterData data = new ParameterData();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
        {
            MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(); //почему вы создаете объект каждый раз?
            myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(row["dt_send_daytime"]);

            data.Cod = row["cod"];
            data.Dt_Begin  = row["dt_beg"];
            data.Dt_Period_End = row["dt_period_end"];  

            myTimer.Parameter = data;

            myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;                  
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39908/discussion-on-answer-by-sem---).

Comment: Спасибо, мы уже все  обсудили в чате.